# Change name of Variable while in a loop

Tags: bash, loops, variables

I have this idea in mind:

I have this number: CN=`20`

and a list=( "xa1-" "xa2-" "xb1-" "xb2-")

and this is my script:

```
for a in "${list[@]}"; do

        let "CN=$(($CN+1))"
        echo $CN

Output:
21
22
23
24
```

I am trying to create a loop where it creates the following variables, which will be referenced later in my script:

```
fxp0_$CN="fxp-$a$CN"

fxp0_21="fxp-xa1-21"
fxp0_22="fxp-xa2-22"
fxp0_23="fxp-xb1-23"
fxp0_24="fxp-xb2-24"
```

However, I have not been able to find a way to change the variable name within my loop. Instead, I was trying myself and I got this error when trying to change the variable name:

scripts/srx_file_check.sh: line 317: **fxp0_21=fxp0-xa2-21**: command not found

Answer (score 2):

After playing around I found the solution!

```
for a in "${list[@]}"; do

        let "CN=$(($CN+1))"
        fxp_int="fxp0-$a$CN"
        eval "fxp0_$CN=${fxp_int}"
    done

    echo $fxp0_21
    echo $fxp0_22
    echo $fxp0_23
    echo $fxp0_24
    echo $fxp0_25
    echo $fxp0_26
    echo $fxp0_27
    echo $fxp0_28
```

Output:

```
fxp0-xa1-21
fxp0-xa2-22
fxp0-xb1-23
fxp0-xb2-24
fxp0-xc1-25
fxp0-xc2-26
fxp0-xd1-27
fxp0-xd2-28
```

Answer (score 1):

One common method for maintaining a dynamically generated set of variables is via arrays.

When the variable names vary in spelling an associative array comes in handy whereby the variable 'name' acts as the array index.

In this case since the only thing changing in the variable names is a number we can use a normal (numerically indexed) array, eg:

```
CN=20
list=("xa1-" "xa2-" "xb1-" "xb2-")

declare -a fxp0=()

for a in "${list[@]}"
do
    (( CN++ ))
    fxp0[${CN}]="fxp-${a}${CN}"
done
```

This generates:

```
$ declare -p fxp0
declare -a fxp0=([21]="fxp-xa1-21" [22]="fxp-xa2-22" [23]="fxp-xb1-23" [24]="fxp-xb2-24")

$ for i in "${!fxp0[@]}"; do echo "fxp0[$i] = ${fxp0[$i]}"; done
fxp0[21] = fxp-xa1-21
fxp0[22] = fxp-xa2-22
fxp0[23] = fxp-xb1-23
fxp0[24] = fxp-xb2-24
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule can I tell you that it's not a good idea to modify names of variables within loops.

There is, however, a way to do something like that, using the `source` command, as explained in [this URL with some examples](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/source-command-in-linux-with-examples/). It comes down to the fact that you treat a file as a piece of source code.

Good luck